# Shopify Storefront GraphQL filtering products within a collection

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

According to this documentation:
https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/products/filter-products#query-products-by-type

We should be able to filter products within a collection using `collectionByHandle`.

I have created a very basic test query in the Shopify GraphiQL App explorer tool. When I run the documented query, it returns all products, not filtering at all. See below:

[image: GraphQL example query]

This looks like a bug with the API right? Or am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 4):

OK this turned out to be a configuration issue. To allow filtering by product type, it needs to be turned on in the admin for your store. If you navigate to:
Online Store > Navigation

... and scroll to the bottom, you will see where you can add allowed filters:
[image]

Even if it says your theme doesn't support filters, it will still change the way the API behaves.

Comment: Awesome! This fixed the filtering issue. Shopify needs to rectify its storefront api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the filters param of products query seem to be ineffective and returning me all the products in the collection.
I can't find the "allowed filters" option.
Currently I'm using the Storefront API as an external app, all works fine except that.

Here the code.

```
 query (
      $collectionHandle: String, $product_filters: [ProductFilter!], $nQueryElements: Int
    ) {
      collection(handle: $collectionHandle) {
        title
        products(first: $nQueryElements filters: $product_filters) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
          }
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              title
              vendor
              availableForSale
              id
              handle
              productType
              variants(first: 40) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    selectedOptions {
                       name
                      value
                        }
                    title
                    compareAtPriceV2 {
                      amount
                    }
                    image {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              priceRange {
                maxVariantPrice {
                  amount
                }
              }
              images(first: 1) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    url(transform:  { maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 700 })
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

const variables = { collectionHandle: this.pageURL, nQueryElements: this.nQueryElements, lastCursor: this.queryCursor.last, firstCursor: this.queryCursor.first, product__filters: [{ productVendor: "ASPESI", },], };

Thanks to who can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be better for you to create a new question with this information instead of as an answer to the original question - you'll get better community help that way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done now. This [post on the Shopify forum](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/query-all-products-with-a-given-metafield-value/m-p/1785157/highlight/true#M319505) explains it perfectly with the latest API.

In case that post gets deleted, I'm going to put the info below:

We can now filter by metafields but through a collection. https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/products-collections/filter-products#query-products-by-metafi...

Requirements:

- The metafield must have been added as a filter in the "Search &
  Discovery app" or the Filters in the Navigation settings.
- The metafield must be of one of these types: single_line_text_field,
  boolean, numeric_integer, numeric_decimal
- The Storefront API used must be 2022-04 or higher. I tested it with
  2022-10
- The metafield must be exposed to the Storefront API

Knowing that as of today, we have a limit of 5000 products for filters to work in a normal store (see https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/search-and-discovery/filters)

I decided to test if that restriction applies to the Storefront API, I tested it with a collection with 11769 products and I was able to get filtered results as expected. So it seems that at this stage we don't have this limitation in the Storefront API
.